# How to configure systemd so that PHP can use memcached unix socket?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, unix-sockets, memcached

I'm in the process of upgrading from Ubuntu Server 16.04 to 18.04 and at the same time upgrading from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.

In `/etc/memcached.conf` I added:

```
-s /tmp/memcached.sock
-a 666
```

When I restart the service, I see:

```
srw-rw-rw- 1 memcache memcache 0 Nov 13 03:44 /tmp/systemd-private-7fc3b73707084a93bcc6abd22001eb7e-memcached.service-oIF206/tmp/memcached.sock=
```

How can I configure systemd to know where the unix socket is?

Comment: You have made tests right? Most of the sites written for php 5 breaks in php 7

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro The sites on my server all use popular packages such as WordPress and MediaWiki. I haven't put any of them on the new server until I can verify everything is working, but I haven't even gotten that far as I discovered this issue with unix sockets for memcached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

systemd has `PrivateTmp=true` for memcached.service

One way would be to override `PrivateTmp`, specifically for the `memcached.service`, i.e.

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/memcached.service.d
echo "[Service]" > /etc/systemd/system/memcached.service.d/override.conf
echo "PrivateTmp=false" >> /etc/systemd/system/memcached.service.d/override.conf
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart memcached
```

That would change the memcached.service back to using `/tmp`, rather than `/tmp/systemd-private-...`

Assuming you want to use memcached for session handling; Once you've verified that `/tmp/memcahced.sock` exists with the correct permissions, in `/etc/php.ini` or `/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini` change session support.

```
[Session]
extension=memcached.so
session.save_handler="memcached"
session.save_path="/tmp/memcached.sock"
```

If it exists, comment out `session.save_handler=files`.